# Make gRPC-web working in cross-env js library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, server-side-rendering, grpc-web

I'm trying to build a JS library which is able to make gRPC requests (using HTTP for transport) in browser and node (used by Server Side Rendering) in a transparent manner, not dependent of environement. There are already two different libraries providing transport for both environements:

node : @improbable-eng/grpc-web-node-http-transport (NodeHttpTransport)

browser : @improbable-eng/grpc-web (CrossBrowserHttpTransport)

For example NodeHttpTransport is using http package, not available in browser.

```
import { NodeHttpTransport } from "@improbable-eng/grpc-web-node-http-transport";
import { grpc } from "@improbable-eng/grpc-web";

...

// contrcutor of my service

// setup client for browser
this.rpcBrowser = new GrpcWebImpl(grpcGatewayUrl, {
      transport: grpc.CrossBrowserHttpTransport({ withCredentials: true }),
      debug: false,
});
this.clientBrowser = new GrpcClient(this.rpcBrowser);

// setup client for node
this.rpcNode = new GrpcWebImpl(this.grpcGatewayUrl, {
      transport: NodeHttpTransport(),
      debug: false,
});
this.clientNode = new GrpcClient(this.rpcNode);


...

// on every gRPC requests I get the client for the current env with this function 
 getClient() {
    const isServer = typeof window === "undefined";

    if (isServer) {
      return this.clientNode;
    }

    return this.clientBrowser;
 }
...

// so for example I use it like this

public GetAll(){
   return  this.getClient().GetAll()
}
```

However, this code resuts in this error during build.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/node_modules/@improbable-eng/grpc-web-node-http-transport/lib'
```

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/node_modules/@improbable-eng/grpc-web-node-http-transport/lib'
```

I understand it tries to use http package in browser environment.

I see differents solutions for those errors, like set resolve.fallback.http and resolve.fallback.https to false in webpack config but I don't like this option as browser never use http package, as it uses browser transport library.

Is there a proper way to fix it ?